# Why can we assume the constant in the linear factors of the elementary divisors of a $F[x]$-module $V$ is an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, modules

Here $F$ is a field, $F[x]$ is the ring of polynomials in $x$ with coefficients in $F$, $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ of dimension $n$, $T$ is a fixed linear transformation of $V$ by which we make $V$ into an $F[x]$-module.

The following is an excerpt from Section $12.3$, The Jordan Canonical Form of *Abstract Algebra, $\mathit{3^{rd}}$ edition* by Dummit and Foote:

> For the $F[x]$-module $V$ the invariant factors were monic polynomials $a_1(x), a_2(x),\dots, a_m(x)$ of degree at least one (with $a_1(x)|a_2(x)|\dots|a_m(x)$), so the associated elementary divisors are the powers of the irreducible polynomial factors of these polynomials. These polynomials are only defined up to multiplication by a unit and, as in the case of the invariant factors, we can specify them uniquely by requiring that they be monic.

> To obtain the simplest possible elementary divisors we shall assume that the polynomials $a_1(x), a_2(x),\dots, a_m(x)$ factor completely into linear factors, i.e., that the elementary divisors of $V$ are powers $(x-\lambda)^k$ of linear polynomials....

> Under this assumption on $F$, it follows immediately from Theorem $6$ that $V$ is the direct sum of finitely many cyclic $F[x]$-modules of the form $F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$ **where $\mathbf{\lambda\in F}$ is one of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{T}$, corresponding to the elementary divisors of $\mathbf{V}$**.

**My Question**: I don't quite follow the boldface texts. Indeed, each $a_i(x)$ can be written as product of irreducible elements in $F[x]$ since $F[x]$ is a Unique Factorization Domain, and the irreducibles are certainly of the form $x-\lambda$; but why can we assume that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a submodule of $V$ isomorphic to $F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$ (for $k>0$), then $\lambda$ *must* be an eigenvalue.  Indeed, consider the element $v=(x-\lambda)^{k-1}\in F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$.  This is a nonzero vector and $(x-\lambda)v=0$, which says exactly that $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I didn't quite follow "which says exactly that $v$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$". When you say "$v=(x-\lambda)^{k-1}\in F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$", I believe you meant the corresponding element of $\overline{(x-\lambda)^{k-1}}$ in $V$ under the isomorphism between the submodule of $V$ and the component $F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$. I then tried to show that $(x-\lambda)v$ implies $T(v)=\lambda v$, to no avail.

Comment: $(x-\lambda)v=0$ means $xv=\lambda v$ so $T(v)=\lambda v$.

Comment: Precisely-that assumes $T$ acts on elements in $F[x]/(x-\lambda)^k$ the same way as it does on $V$, which, as plausible as it seems, must be justified.

Comment: That's what it means to have an isomorphism of $F[x]$-modules.

Comment: Indeed-Thank you!